# Can't scan from Ricoh Aficio MP C2551 to OSX Mavericks file share

Tags: osx-mavericks

I configure an Address entry to use SMB with \MYMACNAME\SharedDirectoryName and the username and password that has access to that share, but scanning fails.

How do I figure out why my scans are failing to be stored to the SMB share?

The printer is running Software Versions:

System  :   2.05

NIB :   10.61

Web Image Monitor   :   1.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a firmware update, as the older machines do not support the new version of SMB that OS X uses now. Contact Ricoh or a local dealer, and get it updated.

Oh, and the firmware modules you're interested in (from memory) are System/Copy and Network Support.